# How show stacktrace in testng-plugin of Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins Job that have a script that writes an xml report. The xml is equal to this example:

```
     <testng-results>
            <reporter-output>
           </reporter-output>
           <suite name="suite0" failures="0" tests="0">
               <test name="testcase1">
                  <class name="testcase1.class">
                     <test-method name="test1" started-at="2013-10-07T16:20:51Z" finished-at="2013-10-07T16:20:53Z" duration-ms="2754" status="PASS">
                    </test-method>
                 </class>
             </test>
            <test name="test2">
               <class name="test2.class">
                   <test-method name="testcase2" started-at="2013-10-07T16:21:14Z" finished-at="2013-10-07T16:21:19Z" duration-ms="4163" status="FAIL">
                <short-stacktrace>description of the error with a lot of information....
    </short-stacktrace>
    </test-method>
    </class>
    </test>
</suite>
</testng-results>
```

This xml is readed by the testNgplugin and shows me the tests with duration, nº of fails and passed. But the failed tests doesn't show me the stacktrace...¿There is a way to show the description of the error to the user in Jenkins? What tag must i use?